# Find a formula $A(a,b,c,d)$ for the surface area of $S:= \{ (x,y,z) | y+z=2, x \in [a,b], y \in [c,d] \}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

My professor gave us the hint that it was related to the area of the parallelogram formed by two vectors being their cross product, and also that we can say $y=(1-t)c + td$, which would be perfect if a, b, c, and d were vectors, but the statement $x \in [a,b], y \in [c,d]$ seems to indicate they are just scalars indicating positions on the x and y-axis.

Is there a different approach I'm not seeing?

Comment: Hint:  The set S is a plane, whose projection in the $xy$ plane has an area of $(b - a)(d - c)$.  Further, the normal vector to $S$ is the vector $ N = (0, 1, 1) $.  So the angle between this normal vector and the normal vector to the $xy$ plane, satisfies $\cos \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $.  Hence the required area is $(b - a) (d - c)/\cos \theta = \sqrt{2} (b - a) (d - c)$

Comment: @ghasheem Thank you! If I understand correctly, this works because the "rectangle" has been shifted from the y-axis, but not the x-axis, so you can use trig and the angle between the normal vectors to find the new length of $(d-c)/\cos\theta$, but you don't have to change $b-a$ because it wasn't shifted. If the plane had been $x+y+z=2$, would you have to project the normal vector to both the x and y planes in order to apply this same logic?

Comment: If the plane had been $x+y+z=2$, then $\cos \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $ and then the area would be $ \sqrt{3} (b - a) (d - c) $

Comment: @ghasheem Oh wow that was easier than expected. Could you maybe explain graphically why that is? Is it using $a \cdot b = |a||b|\cos \theta$?

Comment: This is a well-known relation between the area of a planar surface $A$ and the area of its projection on some plane $A_p$.  The relation is $ A_p = A \cos \theta $, where $\theta $ is the angle between the normals of the two planes.

Comment: Of course, using dot product between $n_1$ and $n_2$, you get $\cos \theta = \dfrac{n_1 \cdot n_2}{| n_1 | |n_2|} $

Comment: I leave it to you to prove that it is true.